# Make the JFrame scrollable

Tags: java, jframe, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have following JFrame in on which i'm drawing the diagram.
The problem is half of the diagram outside the boundary.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                drawCosetDiagram gp = new drawCosetDiagram();
                f.add(new JScrollPane(gp));
                Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                f.setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Below is a screenshot of the JFrame.
[image]

How Can I make it scroll down, So I can see the complete diagram.
Note: I'm not using Jpanel. The solution I found on internet are using JPanel.

Comment: `drawCosetDiagram` needs to override the `getPreferredSize` method and return the size that the component would prefer in order to render itself, the `JScrollPane` will then use this to determine when the scrollbars are needed

Comment: *"Note: I'm not using Jpanel"* - Then what are you using?  It must some kind component extending from `JComponent`

Comment: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` is a poor choice to try and maximise the window (and I wish people would stop using it), use `Frame#setExtendedState` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer i'm using paintComponent

Comment: Sure, your class is extending from `JComponent` or `JPanel`, so you can override the `paintComponent` method? Otherwise you wouldn't be able to pass it to the `JScrollPane`

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes it is extending JComponent.

Comment: Right, then, override `getPreferredSize` and return the amount of space you need in order to be able to fully render/show the graph

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for guiding me. one more question, Can I get the dimension of paintComponent inside getPreferreSize()?

Comment: Kind of, I've used a rendering algorithm in the past to generate either a model which can be used to calculate the size or render it to a `BufferedImage` which, again, provides the size, and makes it quicker to render

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you provide some code snippet?